# SQL Query loads slower than it says

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to join two tables. When executing the query in myphp admin it returns:

> Showing rows 0 - 24 (7872 total, Query took 0.2034 seconds.)

However the page takes 18 seconds to load limiting the query to 25 rows has no effect. Any suggestions to how I can optimize following query?

```
SELECT table1.id, 
       table2.name, 
       table2.identifier,  
       table1.firstname, 
       table1.lastname, 
       table1.identifier
FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.identifier = table1.identifier
```

Comment: Do an `EXPLAIN` query to make sure you're using indexes. Even if the query is quick, the data transfer between the database and your webserver may not be. It could be your page is loading other thing which increase the load times.

Comment: Try to add TOP 0 to your query and see how long it will take. At first glance it looks like passing 7K rows takes the toll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query takes 0.2034 seconds to run inside the database. That doesn't include time for the application to connect to the DB and sending the query, or reading the results back from the DB, or the roundtrip time for the browser to send the request to the application and receive the result. Those are much bigger sources of latency than simple database queries, especially with PHP and especially on shared hosting.